# Have an issue with loop iMacros/JS

Tags: javascript, imacros

I have here iMacros/JS script for Facebook, which needs to login to FB account from CSV file, then script have second loop `j`, which is sending
20 friend request from 1 account.

The problem is when you change account there is a popup message that you need to verify phone number in this case I need to skip this account and go to other one.

This code means that if on page appears the message it must break from `j` loop:

```
if(iimPlayCode('TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:"_2e9n"')>0) {
    break;}
```

The issues is when script skips this account it as well skips 20 friends URLs in other CSV file.

So `j` loop must always continue where it stops, if "20" request send start with position "21", but when it skips account it as well skips 20 lines in CSV file.

```
var accounts = 10;
var total = 100;
var timeout = 'SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 0\n';
var speed = 'SET !REPLAYSPEED FAST\n';
var error = 'SET !ERRORIGNORE YES\n';

var x = 0;//if no error

//Login to account from csv file
for(var i = 1; i <= accounts; i++) {

    function LogIn() {
        iimPlayCode(speed+'SET !DATASOURCE Facebooklogin.csv\nSET !DATASOURCE_LINE '+i+'\nTAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:EMAIL ATTR=ID:"email" CONTENT={{!COL1}}\nTAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:PASSWORD ATTR=ID:"pass" CONTENT={{!COL2}}\nTAG POS=1 TYPE=LABEL ATTR=class:"uiButton uiButtonConfirm"\n')
    }

    //Check if already logged in then  relog to account from csv file
    if(iimPlayCode(speed+timeout+'TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=CLASS:"_2s25"')>0) {
        iimPlayCode(timeout+'TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ID:"userNavigationLabel"\nTAG POS=2 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Log<SP>Out')
        LogIn();
    } else { LogIn(); }   

 if(x==0) {
        var j = j*20-19;
    } else if (j > 20) {
        x = 0;
    }

    for (j; j <= total; j++) {

        //If Security Check
        if(iimPlayCode('TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:"_2e9n"')>0) {
            x = 1;
            var j = j - 19;
            break;

         } else {
            x = 0;
         }

            //Send Message and Add Friend
            iimPlayCode(speed+error+'SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 0\nSET !DATASOURCE FacebookFriends.csv\nSET !DATASOURCE_LINE '+j+'\nURL GOTO={{!COL1}}\nSET !EXTRACT {{!URLCURRENT}}\nSAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE={{!NOW:yyyy/mm/dd}}.csv\nTAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=HREF:/messages/thread/*\nTAG POS=1 TYPE=TEXTAREA ATTR=CLASS:"br *" CONTENT=""\nTAG POS=1 TYPE=TEXTAREA ATTR=ID:"composerInput" CONTENT=""\nTAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ID:composer_form ATTR=NAME:send\nURL GOTO={{!COL1}}\n')

            if(j==20*i) { break; }
        }
    };//End of loop
```

Comment: The script skips 20 lines in CSV file because you define `j` as `var j = i*20-19;`. So in this expression use another variable instead of `i` that will depend on your security check.

Comment: @Shugar, thank you for your reply, i trued already to add new variable x; which is equal to zero if there is no error, but now script doesn't break "J" loop after 20 requests sent. Can you please fix the part where i made a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need something like this:

```
var accounts = 10;
var total = 100;
var timeout = 'SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 0\n';
var speed = 'SET !REPLAYSPEED FAST\n';
var error = 'SET !ERRORIGNORE YES\n';

var x = 1;  // variable instead of 'i' in 'j'-loop 

//Login to account from csv file
for(var i = 1; i <= accounts; i++) {

    function LogIn() {
        iimPlayCode(speed+'SET !DATASOURCE Facebooklogin.csv\nSET !DATASOURCE_LINE '+i+'\nTAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:EMAIL ATTR=ID:"email" CONTENT={{!COL1}}\nTAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:PASSWORD ATTR=ID:"pass" CONTENT={{!COL2}}\nTAG POS=1 TYPE=LABEL ATTR=class:"uiButton uiButtonConfirm"\n')
    }

    //Check if already logged in then  relog to account from csv file
    if(iimPlayCode(speed+timeout+'TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=CLASS:"_2s25"')>0) {
        iimPlayCode(timeout+'TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ID:"userNavigationLabel"\nTAG POS=2 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Log<SP>Out')
        LogIn();
    } else { LogIn(); }   

    j = 20 * x - 19;
    for (j; j <= total; j++) {

        //If Security Check
        if(iimPlayCode('TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:"_2e9n"')>0)
            break;

        //Send Message and Add Friend
        iimPlayCode(speed+error+'SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 0\nSET !DATASOURCE FacebookFriends.csv\nSET !DATASOURCE_LINE '+j+'\nURL GOTO={{!COL1}}\nSET !EXTRACT {{!URLCURRENT}}\nSAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE={{!NOW:yyyy/mm/dd}}.csv\nTAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=HREF:/messages/thread/*\nTAG POS=1 TYPE=TEXTAREA ATTR=CLASS:"br *" CONTENT=""\nTAG POS=1 TYPE=TEXTAREA ATTR=ID:"composerInput" CONTENT=""\nTAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ID:composer_form ATTR=NAME:send\nURL GOTO={{!COL1}}\n')

        if (j == 20 * x) {
            x++;
            break;
        }
    }
};//End of loop
```